# How to install google play services

Tags: installation, android, installation-package

I have read a lot about this issue and I understand that there I can find `google play servies` in the `extra` tab when opening the SDK, but I didn't find it, please have a look at what I see when I open the SDK.

Note

I am from Syria so I use proxy to download google products, so is there any chance that this `google play services` is forbidden?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is an option in Extra tab, you need to tick that option to download `Google Play Service`.

See the image,

[image]

Just tick the option, and click on the "Install" button at right bottom of the SDK Manager's dialog box.

Comment: I dont have that option, i showed you the image,

Comment: ok lets see into your problem, which ADT version you have ?

Comment: Ok, then go to Help menu, select "Check for Updated", it will updated to the latest version which is 21.0.1 and after that just restart your eclipse. I am sure then you will be able to find the option.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I will do what you have just said, would you please wait for me, +1 to you bty :)

Comment: Yes, i am here till next one hour, take your time.

Comment: Is there any way to update just the ADT ? because when I tried to check for update , a progress bar has appreared and finished with an error :) , the error was about something in my apache tomcat

Comment: ok, which eclipse version you have ?

Comment: I am using `Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857`

Comment: is it possible to delete the ADT then download the last version then install it? if that is ok, will my android projects affects?

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, yes it is possible, but for backup , do one thing, first copy your eclipse & sdk folder to another directory, and then perform uninstallation & installation of ADT.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8115/discussion-between-lucifer-and-william-kinaan)

Comment: I am downloading it, I am afraid that this will take a lot of time cos the internet is slow, however, would you tell me please how to uninstall the adt

Comment: @WilliamKinaan, please come to the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8115/discussion-between-lucifer-and-william-kinaan) for faster conversion

Comment: after updating my ADT and my SDK it works and i can see the `google play services` in my SDK. thanks a lot

Comment: good, now enjoy android coding :)